# Lightning for Outlook Code

Tags: lightning, api, code, outlook, lightning-outlook

Does anyone know whether the code for [Lightning for Outlook](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/06/introducing-lightning-for-outlook.html) is open-source? If yes, where would we download the source files?

If no, does anyone know whether there is an API available? We were wondering whether code the application to upload the files to a separate location.